# Rank (linear algebra) property

Tags: linear-algebra

We assume that $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. If $B$ is any $n \times k$ matrix, 
then
 $$\text{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\text{rank}(A), \, \text{rank}(B))$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induced linear map $T_{AB}$ by $AB$ satisfies $T_{AB}=T_{A}\circ T_{B}$, where $T_{A},T_{B}$ are induced maps by $A,B$ respectively, then $\text{rank}(AB)=\dim\text{Im}~T_{AB}$, but $\text{Im}~T_{AB}=\text{Im}~(T_{A}\circ T_{B})\subseteq\text{Im}~T_{A}$, so $\dim\text{Im}~T_{AB}\leq\dim\text{Im}~T_{A}=\text{rank}A$.

For the rest, use the fact that $\text{rank}(AB)=\text{rank}(AB)^{T}=\text{rank}B^{T}A^{T}\leq\text{rank}B^{T}=\text{rank}B$.

Comment: Why is $\text{rank}B^{T}A^{T}\leq\text{rank}B^{T}$ ?

Comment: Use the result just proved in the first parapragh.

Comment: Because we have proved that $\text{rank}(AB)\leq\text{rank}A$, now set $A$ to be $B^{T}$ and $B$ to be $A^{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, I just proved a formula that you can prove that result from trivially on this page:

[Basis of the image of the product of two matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526892/basis-of-the-image-of-the-product-of-two-matrices/2526930#2526930)

You get the part for rank(B) automatically then for A plug in $(AB)^T$ and use the fact that the transpose of a matrix has the same rank.

Comment: User284331's is far more efficient provided you're familiar with linear transformations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

- The rank of a matrix is the rank of the associated linear map, i.e. the dimension of the image subspace,
- The rank of a matrix is at most equal to the dimension of  its domain.